# LuaJIT FFI pass char** to C function

Tags: lua, ffi, luajit

Been taking a stab at LuaJIT FFI and have run into a curious problem. I have the following code:

```
local ffi = require("ffi")
ffi.cdef [[
    int decode(char* encodedToken, char** payload);
]]

local lib = ffi.load("lib.so")

local function decode(encoded_token)
    local c_encoded_token = ffi.new("char[?]", #encoded_token, encoded_token)
    local c_token = ffi.new("char*[1]")
    lib.decode(c_encoded_token, c_token)

    local resonse = ffi.string(c_token[0])
    return response
end
```

Basically, the shared object has a method to decode an incoming token, and writes the output to `char** payload`. The weird part is, this code works when I run a single iteration of the `decode` function, but when run in a loop, causes `Segmentation fault`.

This leads me to believe there is a memory leak with my `ffi.new("char*[1]")` allocation. I even tried wrapping it in a `ffi.gc` call, which didn't help either:

```
local c_token = ffi.gc(ffi.new("char*[1]"), ffi.free)
-- do stuff
c_token = nil
```

This is the first time I'm trying out FFI, so any pointers appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out myself. Apparently it was due to null terminated C string taking up one more character.

This worked:

```
local c_encoded_token = ffi.new("char[?]", #encoded_token + 1, encoded_token)
```